# Show/Hide components after checking the current page url

Tags: javascript, angular

Im searching the best way to show/hide components on my angular application using the current location path like, *homepage*, *loginpage*, *logoutpage*, etc.

I'm suscribed to the router events that gives me the current path, so If Im in the login page I should hide the "navbar-component" and if I'm in the home page I should show it.

This approach should work with different components in different current pages. So I was thinking in this method inside of a `*ngIf`:

**app.component.html**

```
<nav *ngIf="myService.isComponentPartOfTheCurrentPage('navbar')">
   ...some navigation buttons here
</nav>
```

**myService.ts**

```
isComponentPartOfTheCurrentPage(componentName: string): boolean {
  const url = getCurrentPath(); // This works fine
  return currenPathContainsThisComponent(componentName, url); // This is gonna return true or false.
}
```

The main problem with this approach is that the angular cycling is calling this function a lot of times. Also I've read some blogs that not recommend this king of things.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

In the subscription to your route events update a behavior subject on the service with the current

```
section$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

in your route sub

```
sections$.next(section);
```

then in your component you listen to the behaviour subject with the async pipe

```
section$ = this.service.section$;
```

and in the template

```
<nav *ngIf="section$ | async as section">
   <div *ngIf="section === 'navbar'">Something</div>
</nav>
```

The section variable will imagically update each time the behavior subject emits.

Comment: The section value should not be the name of the component, it should be url name... like: "login", "home", "logout". ...Why?, because 'm gonna show/hide components after check the current page. Example: if I'm in the login page, I should hide the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

You could watch for router events, specifically `NavigationEnd`, assign the current route to an observable and then do the checks in the components for what route we are currently on.

Service:

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from "@angular/router";
import { filter, map } from "rxjs/operators";

currentRoute$: Observable<string>;

constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.currentRoute$ = router.events.pipe(
    filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map((e: NavigationEnd) => e.url)
  );
}
```

Then listen to the observable using async pipe and do the checks

```
*ngIf="(myService.currentRoute$ | async) === '/login'"
```

You can also perhaps use `includes` if you need to check that if that url fragment is included in url, you can then do:

```
*ngIf="(myService.currentRoute$ | async).includes('login')
```